Do Monitor.Pulse and Monitor.Wait enter kernel mode?
Monitor.Wait() and Monitor.Pulse() are supposed to be more performant than using EventWaitHandle derived classes such as ManualResetEvent per this source.

In terms of performance, calling Pulse takes around a hundred
nanoseconds on a 2010-era desktop—about a third of the time it takes
to call Set on a wait handle.

This performance gain has for sure to do with how the CLR is helping out - internal data structures, sync blocks etc. Trying to understand the source code that is mostly implemented in c/c++ is difficult for me as a c# developer and the closest I managed to get to a deep-dive is from this answer which unfortunately falls a little short of providing a complete explanation:

From here we get to Object::Wait (line 531), then going to
SyncBlock::Wait (line 3442). At this point we have most of the meat of
the implementation and there's quite a bit to it.
Given all of the above and getting back to what you asked re a simpler
implementation, I'd be wary of simplifying Monitor.Wait(). There is a
lot going on under the hood and it'd be very easy to make a mistake
and have potential bugs in an alternative implementation.

In the code for SyncBlock::Wait one can find:
 CLREvent* hEvent;
 ...
 // Before we enqueue it (and, thus, before it can be dequeued), reset the event
 // that will awaken us.
 hEvent->Reset();

From this answer by Hans Passant on a related question of whether Monitor.Enter() is entering kernel mode:

There's a need to get the operating system's thread scheduler
involved so a CLREvent is used. It is dynamically created if necessary
and its WaitOne() method is called. Which will involve a kernel
transition.

So, my questions are

Do Monitor.Wait() and Monitor.Pulse() enter kernel mode via CLREvent method invocations in their implementation. (Is it even conceivably possible for them to work without OS involvement?)

If yes, what makes them more performant than the using the thin OS handle wrappers AutoResetEvent and ManualResetEvent?



https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/managed-object-internals-part-2-object-header-layout-and-the-cost-of-locking/ is a good start. By default it uses CmpExchg to grab the lock, otherwise it spins for a bit and keeps trying, otherwise it creates a Win32 Event. So in low to medium contention scenarios it's much more efficient than always creating an Event. A lot of the logic is here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/2bd15868f12ace7cee9999af61d5c130b2603f04/src/coreclr/vm/syncblk.cpp#L1556

@Charlieface so it still looks MonitorEnter logic?

What do you mean?

@Charlieface you could consider posting your previous comment as an answer. I would upvote your answer, but I won't upvote your comment because comments have the purpose of improving the question, not answering it.

@TheodorZoulias Dunno, it's just a TLDR of a rather long article. Link only answers are also discouraged. You're welcome to write an answer yourself.

@Charlieface  maybe I have worded the question in a confusing way. The article you linked descibes Monitor.Enter. I know how this works and it's fairly obvious. What I don't know is how Monitor.Wait and Monitor.Pulse work in tandem with the CLREvent(base) class.

@TheodorZoulias the question is - can the runtime implement Monitor.Wait and Monitor.Pulse without relying on kernel events - i.e. its own tracking of which threads are blocked, waking threads in a manual way (has the capability from GC) etc.

tinmanjk I haven't studied the Wait/Pulse at the implementation level. I only know how to use it.

@TheodorZoulias I think I found a bit of an explanation by Joe Duffy from an blog post https://joeduffyblog.com/2007/06/24/clr-monitors-and-sync-blocks/
"Condition variables are implemented slightly differently" than Monitor.Enter.

Joe Duffy provides an overview explanation in his 2007 blog post of how Condition Variables i.e. Monitor.Wait/Monitor.Pulse are implemented:

Condition variables are implemented slightly differently. Each CLR
thread object has a single event object dedicated to it. The first
time a thread calls Wait on a condition variable, the event is lazily
allocated. And then the thread simply places its own thread-local
event into a list of events associated with the monitor. Registering
the event also requires inflation to a sync block, if it hasn’t
happened already, because obviously the event list can’t be stored in
the object header. When a Pulse happens, the pulsing thread just
signals the first event in the list... When a PulseAll occurs, the pulsing thread
walks the whole list and signals each.

This seems to still be the case looking at the source code for SyncBlock::Pulse and SyncBlock::PulseAll
void SyncBlock::Pulse()
{
    WaitEventLink  *pWaitEventLink;

    if ((pWaitEventLink = ThreadQueue::DequeueThread(this)) != NULL)
        pWaitEventLink->m_EventWait->Set();
}

void SyncBlock::PulseAll()
{
    WaitEventLink  *pWaitEventLink;

    while ((pWaitEventLink = ThreadQueue::DequeueThread(this)) != NULL)
        pWaitEventLink->m_EventWait->Set();
}

Now the question is if this event object is a kernel event object.
From the source code of SyncBlock::Wait
 // First time this thread is going to wait for this SyncBlock.
CLREvent* hEvent;
if (pCurThread->m_WaitEventLink.m_Next == NULL) {
    hEvent = &(pCurThread->m_EventWait);
}
else {
    hEvent = GetEventFromEventStore();
}
waitEventLink.m_WaitSB = this;
waitEventLink.m_EventWait = hEvent;
waitEventLink.m_Thread = pCurThread;
waitEventLink.m_Next = NULL;
waitEventLink.m_LinkSB.m_pNext = NULL;
waitEventLink.m_RefCount = 1;
pWaitEventLink = &waitEventLink;
walk->m_Next = pWaitEventLink;

// Before we enqueue it (and, thus, before it can be dequeued), reset the event
// that will awaken us.
hEvent->Reset();

// This thread is now waiting on this sync block
ThreadQueue::EnqueueThread(pWaitEventLink, this);

isEnqueued = TRUE;

CLREvent inherits from CLREventBase. By looking at its methods it seems like a class that is supposed to help in the hosting abilities of the CLR -
// Create an Event that is host aware
void CreateAutoEvent(BOOL bInitialState);
void CreateManualEvent(BOOL bInitialState);
// Create an Event that is not host aware
void CreateOSAutoEvent (BOOL bInitialState);
void CreateOSManualEvent (BOOL bInitialState);

The IHostManager interface has a very similar if not identical API and its purpose:

Provides methods that allow the common language runtime (CLR) to
create synchronization primitives by calling the host instead of using
the Win32 synchronization functions.

From the official clr-code-guidelines:

We have the following approved synchronization mechanisms in the CLR:
...
Events: A host can provide event handles that replace the Win32 events.

So, it seems that the default CLREvent that is created is a Win32 event.
This was confirmed by the author of this blogpost with a bit of WinDbg work while trying to determine what event object is used by Monitor.Enter - an AutoResetEvent.
From what I could dig deeper in the call stack of Monitor.Wait, this event is an initially set ManualResetEvent - for example here
handle = new CLREvent;
_ASSERTE (handle != NULL);
handle->CreateManualEvent(TRUE);
return handle;

and here
bool CreateManualEvent(bool initialState)
{
    m_hEvent = CreateEvent(nullptr, true, initialState, nullptr);
    return IsValid();
}

which is consistent with its use in Syncblock::Wait from above
// Before we enqueue it (and, thus, before it can be dequeued), reset the event
// that will awaken us.
hEvent->Reset();

In conclusion, by default (no host overrides) calls to Monitor.Wait and Monitor.Pulse(All) will enter kernel mode since they rely on OS events.
